# How to migrate from Yii to Woocommerce Wp, Still keep to old database (table,rows)

Tags: database, wordpress, yii, woocommerce

I have an e-commerce website writen by yii framework. I want to rebuild with woocommerce on wordpress. And I want to keep old database (all table, rows). But wordpress save data on a different way (metadata).

what is solution in this case, how to import old database and custom field same my old database?

P/s: thanks for advance and sorry about my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do this:

First, you must create the post using `wp_insert_post`:

```
wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Second, you must add the appropriate metadata using `add_post_meta`:

```
add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta

What you end up with is something like this psuedo-code:

```
$yii_products = (get products from yii db.  Perhaps init a new PDO connection to connect to that db.)

foreach($yii_products as $product)
{
  //Create post array from existing datatype in yii
  $post = array(
    'title' => $product->title,
    ...
  );

  //Save post
  $post_id = wp_insert_post($post);

  //Add metadata
  //some_yii_field_name could be 'color', 'size' or whatever woocommerce uses
  add_post_meta($post_id, 'some_yii_field_name', $product->some_yii_field_name);
}
```

This will create all of your new post types and with the appropriate metadata.  I would put this code into a throw-away plugin used only for migration.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks so much. I think that I have understand your way. thanks again

Comment: No problem.  If this helps, I would appreciate if you accept the answer.  Thanks!