# Wordpress plugin to automate posts being generated based on backend tables?

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I am a long time Wordpress user looking to use the tool as a CMS to generate a website which will have individual posts about hundreds of specs on products that I have stored in a backend MySQL table. Is there a plugin or a tool that will help me auto generate these posts? For each post, I would like it to have the same format of title (one column) so that the URL will look like: http://www.domain.com/product1specs etc. Each post will contain a description (another column) and show a graph (data stored in another column).

Or do I even need to create posts? Is there a way to do this dynamically? So if someone goes to www.domain.com/product1 than it will automatically look in the database to find out what it should display for product1?

I believe there are other ways to do this with an PHP framework such as Code Igniter but I would like to stick with Wordpress because I am familiar with it and have other Wordpress plugins/themes I would like to leverage.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a plugin but take a look at this answer which basically required the same thing:

[How to migrate from Yii to Woocommerce Wp, Still keep to old database (table,rows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749046/how-to-migrate-from-yii-to-woocommerce-wp-still-keep-to-old-database-table-row/21749962#21749962)

Comment: That is very helpful thank you! I am surprised there are no plugins out already that assist with this process? Something like this: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/faq/ seems good but what about users that want to continuously import data off of the old backend system? I feel like there should be a way to do this on an ongoing basis.